# Django Model Form not saving to db

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a model for car dealers and I am trying to have a form to create them. The form does not save to the db for some reason however it does reach the redirect. No errors are shown either.

**models.py**

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="dealers/")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Dealers"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def create_dealer_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateDealerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dealer = form.save(commit=False)
            dealer.save()
            return redirect('main:homepage_view')
    else:
        form = CreateDealerForm
    context = {
        "title": "Create - Dealer",
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/create/create_dealer.html", context=context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateDealerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dealer
        fields = ('name', 'phone','website', 'address', 'featured_image',)
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dealer-name-field', 'placeholder': 'Dealer name'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dealer-phone-field', 'placeholder': 'Dealer phone'}),
            'website': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dealer-website-field', 'placeholder': 'Dealer website'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dealer-address-field', 'placeholder': 'Dealer address'}),

        }
```

**create-dealer.html**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container text-center">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.name }}
        {{ form.phone }}
        {{ form.website }}
        {{ form.address }}
        {{ form.featured_image }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create
            Dealer</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It doesn't show any errors because your template does not contain any tags to do so. At least put `{{ form.errors }}` there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay now it's saying `featured_image is required` even though I provided an image

Comment: But you haven't done any of the things you need to [bind files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Perfect, thank you! I just needed to add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to my `<form>` element.

Comment: @DanielRoseman or GTA.sprx please type the solution as answer and then GTA.sprx flag it as correct so that users can see the issue is solved. thanks